# Can I set my website as default homepage for chrome

Tags: java, c#, google-chrome

Am I able to set my website as a home page of Google Chrome browser? I am able to do for IE.

My code for IE.

```
    RegistryKey startPageKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main", true);
    startPageKey.SetValue("Start Page", "http://example.com/");
    startPageKey.Close();
```

Comment: Java or C#? Which one?

Comment: C# or javascript

Answer (score 0):

chrome settings are in %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application 
Data\Google\Chrome\User Data.ChromotingConfig.json and are a little bit encrypted as npocmaka mentioned.

but you can do a workaround like by just pasting following javascript into the "Home Page" pref field (under your Chrome options) and it works as expected when clicking the "Home" button.

```
javascript:(function(){ window.location.href='http://www.google.com/';})();
```

Comment: But how I will do this programmatically

Answer (score 0):

With the help of chrome extension I was able to do same